# Do marginal densities always define a joint density?

Tags: density-function

I was wondering if marginal densities always define the joint density function or if this is only true for statistically independent variables?

PS: I can imagine this is a duplicate but I haven't found anything on the topic via search. If so, please excuse me

Comment: It is not true in general, except, as you mention, for independent variables, for which the joint density is just the product of the marginal densities.  The *conditional* densities, however, do, jointly, define the joint density function:  $f(x|y,z), f(y|x,z), f(z|x,y)$ define $f(x,y,z)$ etc.

Comment: Search for "copula."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counterexample is taking the interval $I=[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure on it and take $(X, Y)(z) = (z, z)$. Now $P_{(X,Y)}(\{(x,y) | x = y\}) = 1$, but as this is a null set on the unit cube, the integral of any integrable function over it would be 0. The marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$ are simply the indicator function on $I$.

Comment: +1.  More generally, when the marginal distribution functions are $F_1$ and $F_2$ and $F_2$ is invertible (as is always the case when it has a density), let $X\sim F_1$ and define a bivariate random variable as $(X, F_2^{-1}(F_1(X))).$